# Probability pitcher throws a strike (normal distribution question)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification, cumulative-distribution-functions

Can someone please let me know if my solutions for these problems are correct?

> Suppose a pitcher in baseball is pitching to a batter, and the perfect
> pitch lands at the catcher's glove right at the "origin" of a
> coordinate system. That is, suppose the y-axis runs vertically from
> the ground to the sky and the x-axis runs horizontally from left to
> right from the pitcher’s vantage point. Suppose the batter is
> right-handed. Hence, a pitch thrown too far in the positive x
> direction would hit the batter.
>
> Assume the pitcher’s fastball’s "x" coordinate is normally distributed
> with mean 0 (a perfect pitch) and variance $\sigma^2$. Suppose the
> batter is 1 foot away from the origin. Assume the pitcher always
> throws at the proper "height" (vertical direction).

.

> a) If the strike zone is 6 inches, find an expression for the
> probability the pitcher throws a strike in terms of $\Phi$. Plot this
> probability as a function of $\sigma^2$ (at least 5 plotted points).

$$P(-0.5 \leq X \leq 0.5) = P(\frac{-0.5}{\sigma} \leq Z 
\leq \frac{0.5}{\sigma})$$

$$=\Phi(\frac{0.5}{\sigma}) - \Phi (\frac{-0.5}{\sigma})$$

I made a table with values for $\sigma$ and the probability and just plotted it as follows:

[image]

> b) Find an expression for the probability the batter gets hit, if the
> batter is 2 feet "wide" and 1 foot away from home plate, as a function
> of $\sigma^2$ (again in terms of $\Phi$). Calculate this probability
> for $\sigma^2 = 0.5$ and $\sigma^2 = 2$.

$$P(1\leq X \leq 3)=P(\frac{1}{\sigma}\leq Z \leq \frac{3}{\sigma})$$

$$=\Phi(\frac{3}{\sigma})-\Phi(\frac{1}{\sigma})$$

When $\sigma^2=0.5:$

$$\Phi(\frac{3}{\sqrt{0.5}})-\Phi(\frac{1}{\sqrt{0.5}})\approx 0.079$$

When $\sigma^2=2:$

$$\Phi(\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}})-\Phi(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})\approx 0.22$$

> c) Ignoring the fact that the pitcher always pitches at the correct
> height, how does this model poorly model this physical situation?

The pitcher being right-handed skews the distribution to left since they're trying to not hit the batter.

> d) How does this model accurately model this situation?

It shows that the closer you pitch to the center, it's more probable you land in the glove.

> e) What does a smaller $\sigma^2$ indicate in this context?

Smaller $\sigma^2$ means they're a better pitcher since the probability of the pitch getting farther from the mean decreases.