# Minimizing and maximizing probabilities in a normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

This is a follow-up question related to a problem I already asked about. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4577261/probability-pitcher-throws-a-strike-normal-distribution-question) is my previous question but I'm stuck on a different part.

> Suppose a pitcher in baseball is pitching to a batter, and the perfect
> pitch lands at the catcher's glove right at the "origin" of a
> coordinate system. That is, suppose the y-axis runs vertically from
> the ground to the sky and the x-axis runs horizontally from left to
> right from the pitcher’s vantage point. Suppose the batter is
> right-handed. Hence, a pitch thrown too far in the positive x
> direction would hit the batter.
>
> Assume the pitcher’s fastball’s "x" coordinate is normally distributed
> with mean 0 (a perfect pitch) and variance $\sigma^2$. Suppose the batter is
> 1 foot away from the origin. Assume the pitcher always throws at the
> proper "height" (vertical direction).

**Suppose the probability the batter hits the pitch is $\frac{1}{(S-80)^2}$ where $S$ is the speed of the pitch in mph, $S >= 81$. Suppose the variance of the pitcher is $\sigma^2(S)=(S-80)^3$ for $S >= 81$. Assuming the event that the pitch hits and where they land are independent, find the pitching speed that minimizes the probability of a hit and maximizes the probability of a strike. (You will use a CAS, but you must use methods of continuous optimization to argue your case.**

This is my attempted solution:

The probability of a strike is $$\Phi(\frac{0.5}{\sigma})-\Phi(\frac{-0.5}{\sigma})$$

So taking derivative would be:

$$\frac{d}{dS} \Phi(\frac{0.5}{(S-80)^{3/2}})- \Phi(\frac{-0.5}{(S-80)^{3/2}})$$

Taking the derivative of cdf would give us the pdf of a normal dist.

$$g(\frac{0.5}{(S-80)^{3/2}})(0.5)(-\frac{3}{2(S-80)^{5/2}}) - g(\frac{-0.5}{(S-80)^{3/2}})(-0.5)(-\frac{3}{2(S-80)^{5/2}})$$

$g(x)$ is the pdf of a normal dist with $\mu=0, \sigma=(S-80)^{3/2}$

When we evaluate all of this we get:

$$\frac{-3}{4(S-80)^{5/2}}*\frac{1}{(S-80)^{3/2}\sqrt{2\pi}}*e^{-1/2(\frac{0.5}{(S-80)^3})^2}*2$$

$$=\frac{-3e^{-1/2(\frac{0.5}{(S-80)^3})^2}}{2(S-80)^5\sqrt{2\pi}}$$

I need to set this equal to zero but there is no value of $S$ for which this function equals zero.

I graphed the probability of a hit i.e. $\frac{1}{(S-80)^2}$ and I was going to also graph the probability of a strike i.e. $\Phi (\frac{0.5}{(S-80)^{3/2}})- \Phi(\frac{-0.5}{(S-80)^{3/2}})$.

Then I was going to find where they intersect and plug that into the derivative of the probability of a hit and the derivative of a probability of a strike and see that both those values are close to zero.

Is this the right approach?

EDIT: $S$ is just a real variable, non-random (the pitcher decides)

Comment: Sorry, your question is a bit hard to understand without knowing baseball rules, can you please explicitly write what random variables you have, what do you know about their distribution, and how your probability relates to them? Anyway, if you want to find a maximum of a function and derivative of it is everywhere negative (like in this case) - this means that maximum is on the left point of the interval you consider. Also, it's a bit strange that you substitute $\sigma$ into pdf that already accounts for variance.

Comment: @mihaild Sorry about that. I will update now.